# Ordering the execution of two threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, debian

I wanna write two threads, first will read a string from the console, and the second will output the number of characters in it.

To do so, I have to set the order of executing the threads, reading first, writing second.

Also I want one thread to execute at the time.

How can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *printCharacterNumber(void *ptr);
void *readMessage(void *ptr);

int main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   int iret1, iret2;

   iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, printMessage, NULL);
   iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, printCharacterNumber, NULL);

   pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

   return 0;
}

void *readMessage(void *ptr)
{
   char *message;
   fscan("%s", &message);
}

void *printCharacterNumber(void *ptr)
{
   printf("%s", message); // I'll add counting when it will work
}
```

Comment: Your code does not even compile. `message` should be compilation unit `static` or global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest interest of genine (pthread) threads is to enable parallel execution (taking profit of the several cores most laptops and desktops have)...
Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) ...

You may want to use barriers. Read more about [pthread_barrier_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) & [pthread_barrier_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html)

If you want to serialize some counter, you could use (with recent C11 compilers, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9) some [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), or more usually a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), see [pthread_mutex_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) & [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) etc....:

```
 static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;

 static long counter;

 void increment_serialized_counter (void) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
     counter++;
     pthread_mutex_unclock(&mtx);
 }

 long get_serialized_counter (void) {
    long r = 0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    r = counter;
    pthread_mutex_unclock(&mtx);
    return r;
 }
```

You probably should use a mutex for your `message` variable, if it was static!