# How to keep data for progress bar

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

My program downloads files from servers, and parse it.

For download files i have got a bar, but i want to make bar for parsing.

Parsing take a lot of time, and power, so my solution dont have to use a lot of power.

`few servers -> few files -> line in file`

I.e in one time, i download files from servers (about 4-5 files) and when downloaded, just start parsing.

But when servers is more than 1, my program download files from two servers so i have 2x more files. Files name on servers are the same but when i download file, i change name of these files to "world"+"orginalfile.txt"

I thought about something like that:
`map<int server,std::map<int file(<make it enum),{current line, max lines} >> (struktura)`

Because when reading file, i want to make emit to send data to window.
When start reading i want to send `(file,lines_in_file,server)`
And when reading send `(file,current_line,world)`
Then in window which read this data push this data to some variable (like above example) and run second function to calculate progress bar.

i.e

> servers[] -> files [] -> thread download -> thread reading (these
>   threads start per file, so if servers are 2 and files 4 these threads
>   start 8x) -> emit init signal (send file,lines_in_file,server_number)
>   + emit (currentLineWhenReading,file,server)  signal when reading line-per-line

So how to make it the best, to get a lot of data and hold it + use litte power to calculate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse in a separate thread. Increment (with mutex) some counter while parsing (or use some atomic increment), like e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221716/841108).

<sup>Probably the parsing thread is mostly IO bound. So it will most often wait for disk IO. In that case, the small overhead of mutex locking is insignificant.</sup>

In the main GUI thread, set up things (e.g. some [Qt timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/timers.html)...) to read every second the parse counter (with mutex), and update the progress bar

Comment: Do you mean one counter while parsing for these threads (i.e `int counter`? But mutex dont slow parsing operation? And how to send pointer as arg to this var via reference in std::async ?